# iOS Developer Enterprise Program can be used for OTA?

Tags: ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program, ota

In the Apple Developer Portal I have used an In-house Provisional Profile for distribution.
Now our license has been renewed with the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, and I get this error when updating my app.

[image: Error]

Can the iOS Developer Enterprise Program be used for Over-the-Air distribution?

Comment: Is the `deviceID` of the Device included in the profile you are using for OTA ?

Comment: for OTA we don't want to add the device id.... because i have used before...

Answer (score 0):

At first check if you can install the App via iTunes or the IPCU. If that works, you may have a problem with your plist file.